# Use and modify variables in tensorflow bijectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-probability

In the reference [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10604) for TensorFlow Distributions (now [Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/)), it is mentioned that TensorFlow `Variable`s can be used to construct `Bijector` and `TransformedDistribution` objects, i.e.:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

tf.enable_eager_execution()

shift = tf.Variable(1., dtype=tf.float32)
myBij = tfp.bijectors.Affine(shift=shift)

# Normal distribution centered in zero, then shifted to 1 using the bijection
myDistr = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
            distribution=tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.),
            bijector=myBij,
            name="test")

# 2 samples of a normal centered at 1:
y = myDistr.sample(2)
# 2 samples of a normal centered at 0, obtained using inverse transform of myBij:
x = myBij.inverse(y)
```

I would now like to modify the shift variable (say, I might compute gradients of some likelihood function as a function of the shift and update its value) so I do

```
shift.assign(2.)
gx = myBij.forward(x)
```

I would expect that `gx=y+1`, but I see that `gx=y`... And indeed, `myBij.shift` still evalues to `1`.

If I try to modify the bijector directly, i.e.:

```
myBij.shift.assign(2.)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

Computing gradients also does not work as expected:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    gx = myBij.forward(x)
grad = tape.gradient(gx, shift)
```

Yields `None`, as well as this exception when the script ends:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method GradientTape.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.eager.backprop.GradientTape object at 0x7f529c4702e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py", line 765, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'context'
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: I got it working with a graph/session, so it seems there is an issue with eager execution...

Note: I have tensorflow version 1.12.0 and tensorflow_probability version 0.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using eager mode, you will need to recompute everything from the variable forward. Best to capture this logic in a function;

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions

tf.enable_eager_execution()

shift = tf.Variable(1., dtype=tf.float32)
def f():
  myBij = tfp.bijectors.Affine(shift=shift)

  # Normal distribution centered in zero, then shifted to 1 using the bijection
  myDistr = tfd.TransformedDistribution(
            distribution=tfd.Normal(loc=0., scale=1.),
            bijector=myBij,
            name="test")

  # 2 samples of a normal centered at 1:
  y = myDistr.sample(2)
  # 2 samples of a normal centered at 0, obtained using inverse
  # transform of myBij:
  x = myBij.inverse(y)
  return x, y
x, y = f()
shift.assign(2.)
gx, _ = f()
```

Regarding gradients, you will need to wrap calls to `f()` in a `GradientTape`

Comment: Thanks, I see! Now if I don't want to simply sample the function again, but (for instance) compute the likelihood of some fixed data using `myDistr.log_prob()`, and gradient-ascend the shift variable to maximise that likelihood: does it mean I have to re-create the bijection and transformed distribution object for each step? That seems to involve a lot of overhead (especially if the bijection is a complex normalising flow) compared to what is possible in "regular" graph mode...?

Comment: Yes, you should think of using eager mode more or less like using python floats or numpy arrays. If you change the value of shift, and want to compute some chain using its updated value, you have to repeat the computation. The Bijector[s] will have converted `shift` to a tensor (`tf.convert_to_tensor`), which induces a `read` on the variable and returns a `tf.Tensor` with a fixed `.numpy()` value acquired at the time it was read.

Note that keras does things a little differently, and we are looking at a revamped trainable layers API in TFP.